# Identify linked documents (document trees/lineages) using tidyverse

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have many text documents (`items`) that consist of a unique item number (`item_nr`) and a text (`text`)

The items might be linked to none, one or multiple other items over their `item_nr` in the `text`

I have a few starting items (`start_items`) for which I would like to identify trees (lineages) of all linked items until their ends (an item that does not link another one).

**Example data**

```r
# library
library(tidyverse)

#example data
start_items=structure(list(item_nr = c("31", "32", "33", "34", "35"), text = c("I do not link", 
                                                                           "I link 16", "I link 26", "I link 99", "I do not know")), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                   -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

items=structure(list(item_nr = c("10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", 
                              "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", 
                              "28", "29", "30"), text = c("I have no link", "I link 12", "hi", 
                                                          "how", "are", "you", "I link 17", "I link 18", "I link 19", "here it ends", 
                                                          "I have no link", "thank", "you", "for", "your", "help", "I link 27 and 28", 
                                                          "yes?", "I link 29", "Me neither", "I link 11")), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                          -21L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

# show data
start_items
#> # A tibble: 5 x 2
#>   item_nr text         
#>   <chr>   <chr>        
#> 1 31      I do not link
#> 2 32      I link 16    
#> 3 33      I link 26    
#> 4 34      I link 99    
#> 5 35      I do not know

items
#> # A tibble: 21 x 2
#>    item_nr text          
#>    <chr>   <chr>         
#>  1 10      I have no link
#>  2 11      I link 12     
#>  3 12      hi            
#>  4 13      how           
#>  5 14      are           
#>  6 15      you           
#>  7 16      I link 17     
#>  8 17      I link 18     
#>  9 18      I link 19     
#> 10 19      here it ends  
#> # ... with 11 more rows
```

**What I tried (dplyr approach)**

```r
# make links function
func <-function(x){
  tib <- tibble(item_nr=unlist(str_extract_all(x,"1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-9]")))
  if(nrow(tib)<1){return(tibble(item_nr=c(NA_character_),text=c(NA_character_)))}
  left_join(tib,items) -> res
  return(res)
}

# apply function
start_items %>% 
  group_by(item_nr) %>% 
  mutate(link1=list(func(text))) %>% unnest() %>% 
  group_by(item_nr,text1) %>% 
  mutate(link2=list(func(text1))) %>% unnest() %>% 
  group_by(item_nr,text2) %>% 
  mutate(link2=list(func(text2))) %>% unnest() %>% 
  group_by(item_nr,text3) %>% 
  mutate(link2=list(func(text3))) %>% unnest() -> output

# output
output
#> # A tibble: 6 x 10
#> # Groups:   item_nr, text3 [6]
#>   item_nr text    item_nr1 text1   item_nr2 text2 item_nr3 text3 item_nr4 text4 
#>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>    <chr>   <chr>    <chr> <chr>    <chr> <chr>    <chr> 
#> 1 31      I do n~ <NA>     <NA>    <NA>     <NA>  <NA>     <NA>  <NA>     <NA>  
#> 2 32      I link~ 16       I link~ 17       I li~ 18       I li~ 19       here ~
#> 3 33      I link~ 26       I link~ 27       yes?  <NA>     <NA>  <NA>     <NA>  
#> 4 33      I link~ 26       I link~ 28       I li~ 29       Me n~ <NA>     <NA>  
#> 5 34      I link~ <NA>     <NA>    <NA>     <NA>  <NA>     <NA>  <NA>     <NA>  
#> 6 35      I do n~ <NA>     <NA>    <NA>     <NA>  <NA>     <NA>  <NA>     <NA>
```

However, I have the feeling that my code is quite clumsy and would need a lot of repetition to trace all document trees to their end in my real data (I do not know the tree sizes).

Is there some way to write a function that runs until all trees are fully identified?

Thanks for any hint. I am very fine with a solution that leads to another output format (e.g. nested structure), if more feasible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a fun problem to investigate :-)

Your issue is a classic problem of [recursion](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Recursion_(computer_science)), which is a kinda hard concept the first time you see it.

As you don't know how many recursions there will be, a `long` format is better.

Here, the recursive function will call itself as long as there are links to parse. The escape condition is based on the number of remaining links. However, I added a `max_r` value to avoid being stuck in an infinite loop, in the case you have an item linking to itself (directly or not).

The initiation loop (`if(r==0)`) is only here to prepare the long format, where a single item can be on multiple rows: there is a source item, a current item and a current recursion number. This should be externalized to simplify the function (then you start at `r=1`) if you don't care to change your dataset format.

```r
library(tidyverse)
                                                                    
recursive_func = function(df, r=0, max_r=10){
  if(r==0){
    df = df %>% 
      transmute(source_item=item_nr,
                item_nr=item_nr,
                rec=0, 
                text=text)
    return(df %>% recursive_func(r=1))
  }
  
  df2 = df %>% 
    filter(rec==r-1) %>% 
    mutate(item_nr = str_extract_all(text,"[1-3][0-9]"),
           rec=r) %>% 
    unnest(item_nr) %>% 
    left_join(items, 
              by=c("item_nr"), suffix=c("_old", "")) %>% 
    select(-text_old)
  
  
  if(nrow(df2)==0 || r>max_r){
    return(df)
  }
  
  bind_rows(df, df2) %>% 
    arrange(source_item, rec) %>% 
    recursive_func(r=r+1)
}


start_items %>% 
  group_by(item_nr) %>%
  recursive_func()
#> # A tibble: 13 x 4
#> # Groups:   item_nr [13]
#>    source_item item_nr   rec text            
#>    <chr>       <chr>   <dbl> <chr>           
#>  1 31          31          0 I do not link   
#>  2 32          32          0 I link 16       
#>  3 32          16          1 I link 17       
#>  4 32          17          2 I link 18       
#>  5 32          18          3 I link 19       
#>  6 32          19          4 here it ends    
#>  7 33          33          0 I link 26       
#>  8 33          26          1 I link 27 and 28
#>  9 33          27          2 yes?            
#> 10 33          28          2 I link 29       
#> 11 33          29          3 Me neither      
#> 12 34          34          0 I link 99       
#> 13 35          35          0 I do not know
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for this marvellous solution. What would be the right solution to buffer the results during the recursions (just in case the process throws an error at some point)?

Comment: @ava you could remove the recursive call (last line of the function) and manually pipe the function multiple times, but this would be a little less elegant. What kind of error are you thinking about?

Comment: I see, thank you. In the real setting  `items` will be web-scraped depending on the results of `str_extract_all`, therefore it is somewhat error-prone. However, I think I can just include some `tryCatch` :)

Comment: @ava a nice way to consider this would be to characterize your error by performing checks on df2 and raising a custom error if something is wrong. Something like `if(nrow(df2)>3) stop("There was an error during recursion ", r, " where df2 had ", nrow(df2), " rows")`.